# marcar uma checkbox e desmarcar as outras

Tags: javascript, html5

Conforme o `Snippet` abaixo, ao clicar em uma `checkbox`, as outras deveriam ser desmarcadas, porém só acontece se clicar nelas da direita para à esquerda, caso eu clique nelas da esquerda para a direita, nada acontece.

---

*Alguém tem idéia do que está acontecendo?*

---

### Explicação:

*Ao selecionar um `checkbox`, aplicarei um filtro X em um campo Y.
Já existem outros `Radio Button` em uso, e meu superior quer que seja usado os `checkbox`.*

```js
var d = document.getElementById('dinheiro');
    var p = document.getElementById('porcentagem');
    var h = document.getElementById('hora');

    function marcaDesmarca() {
        if (d.checked) {
            document.getElementById('porcentagem').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('hora').checked = false;
        } else if (p.checked) {
            document.getElementById('dinheiro').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('hora').checked = false;
        } else if (h.checked) {
            document.getElementById('dinheiro').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('porcentagem').checked = false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div style='position: relative;'>
                <input id="dinheiro" name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="D" onclick="marcaDesmarca()"> <label style='display: contents;'>Dinheiro</label>
                <input id="porcentagem" name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="P" onclick="marcaDesmarca()"> <label style='display: contents;'>Porcentagem</label>
                <input id='hora'  name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="H" onclick="marcaDesmarca()"> <label style='display: contents;'>Hora/Minuto</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Se tu quer marcar só uma opção, `radio button` não seria mais adequado?

Comment: Sim, porém preciso usar os `checkbox`!

Comment: Por qual motivo exatamente?

Comment: Preferência do meu superior e já existem outros `radio button` em uso.

Comment: Se for só uma questão visual, utilize `radio` e defina `appearance` como `checkbox` (veja um [exemplo](https://jsbin.com/weviwusoco/edit?html,css,output)). Desta forma parecerá que são `checkbox`, mas são `radio` e funcionam como `radio`. O que seu superior pediu não faz sentido e você deve orientá-lo a não fazer.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson!

Comment: "O que seu superior pediu não faz sentido e você deve orientá-lo a não fazer.", até brinquei na resposta mas completamente de acordo com essa colocação do @AndersonCarlosWoss.

Comment: Agradeço as respostas e as explicações, serão muito úteis para mim e para outras pessoas também, mas como o @Mathias respondeu primeiro e corretamente, vou marcar a resposta dele como correta!

Comment: A resposta tá correta, mas a abordagem não é boa. Das três ideias a melhor é a do @AndersonCarlosWoss, com toda certeza.

Comment: É a menos pior, eu diria, pois até mudar a aparência de um elemento para outro não é recomendado porquê gerará estranheza no usuário ou ver um `checkbox` e não conseguir marcar mais de uma opção. Embora essa estranheza pode ser contornada se o texto auxiliar ao campo deixar muito bem explícito que será permitido selecionar apenas um item.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você deveria postar como resposta a sua ideia de fazer com que os *radios* tenham aparência de checkbox. É a maneira menos vulnerável a bugs, talvez a única que não vá dar dores de cabeça futuramente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ele está fazendo isso porque é justamente o que o código manda fazer. A melhor alternativa, como já foi citado, seria usar *radio buttons*.

Como isso não é possível, segue uma alternativa que simula o comportamento deles. Perceba que não é necessário fazer um monte de código, é só saber qual foi o *checkbox* que disparou o evento (`caller`) e desmarcar todos exceto ele.

Eu segui o seu padrão de desenvolvimento e como você definiu os eventos direto no HTML, usando o `onclick`, eu alterei a chamada do método para passar como parâmetro o elemento que disparou o evento (`onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)"`).

```js
function marcaDesmarca(caller) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');    
  checks.forEach(c => c.checked = (c == caller) );
}
```

```html
<div style='position: relative;'>
  <input id="dinheiro" name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="D" 
         onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)"> 
  <label style='display: contents;'>Dinheiro</label>
  <input id="porcentagem" name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="P" 
         onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)">
  <label style='display: contents;'>Porcentagem</label>
  <input id='hora'  name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="H" 
         onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)">
  <label style='display: contents;'>Hora/Minuto</label>
</div>
```

Versão pra rodar em qualquer browser.

```js
function marcaDesmarca(caller) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');    
  for(let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    checks[i].checked = checks[i] == caller;   
  }
}
```

```html
<div style='position: relative;'>
  <input id="dinheiro" name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="D" 
         onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)"> 
  <label style='display: contents;'>Dinheiro</label>
  <input id="porcentagem" name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="P" 
         onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)">
  <label style='display: contents;'>Porcentagem</label>
  <input id='hora'  name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="H" 
         onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)">
  <label style='display: contents;'>Hora/Minuto</label>
</div>
```

Comment: ainda não estou acostumado com essa notação do `es6`, voce pode explicar qual a lógica dentro do `foreach`? você atribui `c` para `c.checked` e depois compara com o `caller`?

Comment: Posso explicar sim, mas não tem nada a ver com ES6. É só uma simples atribuição booleana. Veja: a propriedade `checked` de cada elemento ira receber o resultado da expressão booleana `c == caller`, `caller` é sempre quem chamou o evento, ou seja, se o elemento for o mesmo que chamou o evento, a propriedade `checked` recebe `true`, caso contrário, ela recebe `false`.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly Talvez circundar a expressão com parênteses a torne mais legível.

Comment: Realmente seu código é muito limpo e fácil de entender, apliquei em meu código. Excelente!!

Comment: @LINQ com os parenteses consegui entender melhor! obrigado. mas as arrows functions ainda não funcionam em todos os browsers certo? logo isso precisaria ser "compilado".

Comment: Só os mais modernos. Mas isso é detalhe secundário na resposta, não? O código pode ser alterado para `checks.forEach(function(c) { c.checked = (c == caller) });`

Answer (score 4):

Use o `<input type="radio">` e altere a aparência do elemento para parecer um *`checkbox`*:

```css
input[type='radio']{
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
     -moz-appearance: checkbox;
      -ms-appearance: checkbox;
          appearance: checkbox
}
```

```html
<label for='red'>Vermelho</label>
<input id='red' type='radio' name='selection' checked>

<label for='green'>Verde</label>
<input id='green' type='radio' name='selection'>

<label for='blue'>Azul</label>
<input id='blue' type='radio' name='selection'>
```

Ou alterando a aparência das "caixas" com imagens:

```css
/* Esconde o elemento "padrão" do radiobutton. */
input[type='radio']{
  display: none;
}

/* checkbox ñ marcado */
input[type='radio'] + label::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdAsr.png) no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

/* checkbox marcado */
input[type='radio']:checked + label::before {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOuFX.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input id='red' type='radio' name='selection'>
<label for='red'>Vermelho</label>

<input id='green' type='radio' name='selection'  checked>
<label for='green'>Verde</label>

<input id='blue' type='radio' name='selection'>
<label for='blue'>Azul</label>
```

Comment: Exatamente como o Anderson opinou, fica bom também! Obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: [Não tem por onde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8MqG.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

Ainda acho que seria melhor usar `radio button`, mas ordens são ordens... Segue uma alternativa, ao marcar um `checkbox` é passado o id do mesmo por parâmetro para o `marcaDesmarca(id)` ai o ajuste é feito através do id. O problema do seu código é que se o `checkbox` dinheiro estivesse marcado ele sempre ia cair no primeiro if.

```js
var d = document.getElementById('dinheiro');
var p = document.getElementById('porcentagem');
var h = document.getElementById('hora');

function marcaDesmarca(id) {
  if (id == "dinheiro") {
    document.getElementById('porcentagem').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('hora').checked = false;
  } else if (id == "porcentagem") {
    document.getElementById('dinheiro').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('hora').checked = false;
  } else if (id == "hora") {
    document.getElementById('dinheiro').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('porcentagem').checked = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style='position: relative;'>
  <input id="dinheiro" name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="D" onclick="marcaDesmarca(this.id)"> <label style='display: contents;'>Dinheiro</label>
  <input id="porcentagem" name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="P" onclick="marcaDesmarca(this.id)"> <label style='display: contents;'>Porcentagem</label>
  <input id='hora' name="tipoentrada" type="checkbox" value="H" onclick="marcaDesmarca(this.id)"> <label style='display: contents;'>Hora/Minuto</label>
</div>
```