# Alguém teria uma solução para transformar "checkbox" em "radio"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um código Jquery junto com Js, pois pretendo transformar checkbox em radio, esse código funciona com radios, com apenas um clique no mesmo local ele desmarca o radio caso esteja marcado, e caso o usuário clicar em outro ele desmarca o anterior e assim por diante, até aí tudo bem! mas para funcionar com checkbox mudei as referencias especificando checkbox, porém não procedi e os checkbox se comportam de forma padrão. Alguém teria a solução de como ficaria o código adicionando checkbox no Jquery e eles se comportarem como eu citei acima ?

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("click",function (e) {
        var inp=$(this);
    if (inp.is(".theone")) {
        inp.prop("checked",false).removeClass("theone");
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox[name='"+inp.prop("name")+"'].theone").removeClass("theone");
        inp.addClass("theone");
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class='radioholder'><input type='checkbox' value='test' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test1' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test2' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test3' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test4' name='test'/>
    <input type='checkbox' value='test5' name='test'/></span>
```

Comment: Leitura essencial: [Qual é o impacto de se alterar o comportamento padrão de um elemento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212270/5878)

Comment: Se quer radio, use <input type="radio">; qualquer outra solução é um serviço extremamente precário (não foi bem nessa palavra que eu pensei), a não ser que você tenha realmente uma razão técnica pra fazer a alteração de comportamento (que claramente não é o caso do cenário descrito na pergunta).

Comment: @Bacco a palavra seria gambiarra.

Comment: Não pode ser o mesmo "radio", eu vou incrementar dois tipos de botões a um mesmo elemento, sendo que suas propriedades sejam iguais e que não causem interferência um no outro, um radio e checkbox incrementados ao mesmo elemento mas com estilização diferentes e checagens resultando em diferentes atributos

Comment: Realmente é gambiarra. Não tem praticamente diferença nenhuma alterar a quantidade de radios ou de checkbox, seja lá qual for a estilização. Fica realmente a sugestão de fazer certinho, de quebra vai aprender um pouco mais sobre HTML. Inclusive, no final fica até mais simples do que o remendo com JS

Comment: Você estar certo é gambiarra mesmo, estou testando agora, pois até eu me confundi ao abrir meu código agora pouco, levou 5 minutos pra mim entender ele de novo kkkk

Comment: @ElienayJunior tem hora que a gente precisa fazer umas esquisitices, mas é que nesse seu caso realmente teria sido melhor você ter apresentado a tentativa original com radio, e explicar a razão de não ter dado certo, assim alguém poderia propor uma solução para o código "certo". Pense nisso nas próximas postagens para não cair no [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499) - Que é quando você pede ajuda para uma tentativa de solução específica (que nem sempre é a melhor), em vez de perguntar sobre o problema real que deu início à tentativa.

Comment: Eu ia fazer isso, mas o código tá tão bagunçado que me deu vergonha de postar, resultou bem no código a gambiarra funcionou, mas percebi que a gambiarra vai bem mais longe do que eu quero, acarretou em outro problema, mas prefiro para por aqui, está muito bagunçado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("click",function(){
   
   var inp = $(this);

   // desmarco tudo (menos o clicado) e removo a classe
   $("input:checkbox")
   .not(inp)
   .prop("checked", false)
   .removeClass("theone")

   // verifico se está checado e altero a classe
   inp
   .prop("checked", inp.is(":checked"))
   .toggleClass("theone");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='radioholder'><input type='checkbox' value='test' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test1' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test2' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test3' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test4' name='test'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='test5' name='test'/></span>
```

Comment: Funciona dessa forma, porém! ele não desmarca ao clicar no mesmo, só faltou isso, eu queria que ao mesmo tempo ele desmarcasse e funcionasse dessa mesma forma que vc fez

Comment: Veja agora.....

Comment: Agora a ligação ficou boa, eu vou jogar ele aqui no meu código e ver como se comporta utilizando dois tipos de botões em um mesmo elemento com checagens e atributos diferentes