# Desativar checkbox quando selecionar o próximo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou com um problema relacionado a div oculta que é apresentada ao selecionar o check, como não posso usar o radio button por um motivo de uma função que está sendo utilizada, preciso executar no checkbox, porém ao trocar de checkbox a div anterior continua habilitada, o código está aqui no http://jsfiddle.net/hqLz4kb7/2/

Como posso solucionar isso?

Comment: Leitura importante: [Qual é o impacto de se alterar o comportamento padrão de um elemento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212270/5878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toda vez que for dar *show()* em uma **div**, dê *hide()* em todas as outras.

```
$("#add-festa-p").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $("#add-festa-p-div").show();
    $("#add-festa-k-div").hide();
    $("#add-festa-s-div").hide();
    console.log("Mostra a DIV");
  }
});

$("#add-festa-k").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $("#add-festa-k-div").show();
    $("#add-festa-p-div").hide();
    $("#add-festa-s-div").hide();
    console.log("Mostra a DIV");
  }
});

$("#add-festa-s").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $("#add-festa-s-div").show();
    $("#add-festa-k-div").hide();
    $("#add-festa-p-div").hide();
    console.log("Mostra a DIV");
  }
});
```