# Fazer um select e checkbox ter um comportamento parecido com radio button

Tags: javascript, html, knockoutjs

## Com knockoutjs

Estou com uma dificuldade em pegar valores de `input`  dentro de uma `table` para comparar ele teria que ser como um `radio button`, porém são dois `checkbox`  como pode ser visto no [html](/questions/tagged/html) abaixo:

```js
function DemoItem(id, name) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Selected = ko.observable(false);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.associatedItemIds = ko.observableArray();

    self.init = function () {
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(1, 'One'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(2, 'Two'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(3, 'Three'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(4, 'Four'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(5, 'Five'));
    };
    
    self.toggleAssociation = function (item) {
        if (item.Selected() === true) console.log("dissociate item " + item.id());
        else console.log("associate item " + item.id());
        item.Selected(!(item.Selected()));
        return true;
    };
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Available Items:
<table data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id(), checked: $root.associatedItemIds, click: $root.toggleAssociation" /> 
    <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
    </td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
Associated Item Ids:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.associatedItemIds">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**Observação:** estou utilizando [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) então essa tabela é gerando dinamicamente onde posso ter varias tabela.

Basicamente eu estou tentando fazer como se  `checkbox` fosse igual um `radio button` em um radio group

```js
function DemoItem(id, name) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Selected = ko.observable(false);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.associatedItemIds = ko.observableArray();

    self.init = function () {
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(1, 'One'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(2, 'Two'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(3, 'Three'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(4, 'Four'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(5, 'Five'));
    };
    
    self.toggleAssociation = function (item) {
        if (item.Selected() === true) console.log("dissociate item " + item.id());
        else console.log("associate item " + item.id());
        item.Selected(!(item.Selected()));
        return true;
    };
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();

function marcaDesmarca(caller) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');    
  for(let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    checks[i].checked = checks[i] == caller;   
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Available Items:
<table data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id(), checked: $root.associatedItemIds, click: $root.toggleAssociation"  onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)"/> 
    <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
    </td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
Associated Item Ids:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.associatedItemIds">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Bom minha questão é duplicada dessa"[marcar uma checkbox e desmarcar as outras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211381/marcar-uma-checkbox-e-desmarcar-as-outras)", porém uso o código e veja o que acontece, no meu eu tenho que marca todos o check para funcionar corretamente e ainda no meu projeto que o campos é gerado dinamicamente  ele descamar todos os check que não deveria acontecer, no entanto quando clica no check novamente ele tem que desmarcar quando o mesmo estiver marcado.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro na pergunta o que você deseja fazer, você quer alterar o valor do `select` com base no `ckeckbox`? Ou seja, se os dois `checkbox` estiverem selecionados o `select` tenha um valor e, caso não estejam selecionados o `select` tenha outro valor?

Comment: E possivelmente você não deveria fazer isso: [Qual é o impacto de se alterar o comportamento padrão de um elemento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212270/5878)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria isso que você precisa?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('change', ':checkbox', function(){
    //Verifica se o checkbox clicado está checado
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        //Desmarca os demais checkbox que estão na mesma tabela que o checkbox clicado
        $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
        //Atribui o valor 0 para o select que esteja na mesma tabela que o checkbox clicado
        $(this).closest('table').find('select').prop('value', 0);
    }
  });
  $(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
      //Desmarca os checkbox que estão na mesma tabela do select que teve um valor selecionado
      $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg" data-id="${$index}">

Tabela 1

 <tr>
  <td class="tg-yw4l"><span for="active">Comforme: </span></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" data-bind="checkedValue:Comformity, checked: Comformity" /></td>
</tr>                   
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><span for="active">Oportunidade de Melhoria: </span></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="1" data-bind="checkedValue:OM, checked:OM" id="OM" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><span>Não Conformidade: </span></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
<span>
<select data-bind="value: NonComformityType" id="NonComformityType">
<option value="0" selected>Escolher</option>
<option value="2">Maior</option>
<option value="1">Menor</option>
</select>
</span>
</td>
</tr>

 </table>

<br><br>

<table class="tg" data-id="${$index}">

Tabela 2

 <tr>
  <td class="tg-yw4l"><span for="active">Comforme: </span></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" data-bind="checkedValue:Comformity, checked: Comformity" /></td>
</tr>                   
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><span for="active">Oportunidade de Melhoria: </span></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="1" data-bind="checkedValue:OM, checked:OM" id="OM" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><span>Não Conformidade: </span></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
<span>
<select data-bind="value: NonComformityType" id="NonComformityType">
<option value="0" selected>Escolher</option>
<option value="2">Maior</option>
<option value="1">Menor</option>
</select>
</span>
</td>
</tr>

 </table>
 
<br><br>

<table class="tg" data-id="${$index}">

Tabela 3

 <tr>
  <td class="tg-yw4l"><span for="active">Comforme: </span></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" data-bind="checkedValue:Comformity, checked: Comformity" /></td>
</tr>                   
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><span for="active">Oportunidade de Melhoria: </span></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="1" data-bind="checkedValue:OM, checked:OM" id="OM" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><span>Não Conformidade: </span></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
<span>
<select data-bind="value: NonComformityType" id="NonComformityType">
<option value="0" selected>Escolher</option>
<option value="2">Maior</option>
<option value="1">Menor</option>
</select>
</span>
</td>
</tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: @BrunoH. Editei a resposta colocando duas tabelas diferentes e modificando um pouco o script, agora não está mais interferindo nos `inputs` da outra tabela.

Comment: @BrunoH. Acredito que agora não interfira mais nos inputs de outras tabelas, fiz o exemplo colocando 3 tabelas iguais e só altera os `inputs` da tabela correspondente ao `checkbox` ou `select` clicado.